# cart quantity php

Tags: php, css, sql, cart

I am getting  an error when updating a product in the cart.

> **Notice**:  Array to string conversion in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\cart.php** on line **109**

Line 109 refers to this line in the code below to input that contains `this['qty']` the input type of quantity.

```
<?php

function updatecart(){

global $con;

$ip=getIp(); 

if(isset($_POST['update_cart'])){

foreach($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id){

$delete_product="delete from cart where p_id='$remove_id' AND ip_add='$ip'";

$run_delete = mysqli_query($con, $delete_product);

if($run_delete){   
  echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
    }
}

}

} if(isset($_POST['continue'])){

echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

}
```

Comment: Which line is line 109?

Comment: (Aside: your `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries have SQL injection vulnerabilities).

Answer (score 0):

`$remove_id` is returning an array not a string.

You would need to `var_dump($remove_id)` to see what format the data is being returned.

From there you would be able to identify the key of the inner array.

So you would be passing $remove_id[**key**].

You should consider securing your query also as mentioned in the comments its vulnerable to SQL injection. Check out this [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)